# How to run async.each within async.series in an AWS Lambda function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, async.js

we'e writing a serverless function in AWS Lambda that does the following:

1. Fetches JSON files from AWS S3 (Multiple files).
2. Merges JSON files into one single file.
3. Uploads the new file from (2) back to S3.

To handle this flow, we're trying to use the async library in Nodejs within our Lambda. Here's the code we have so far:

```
'use-strict';

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const async = require('async');

const BUCKET = 'sample-bucket';
const s3path = 'path/to/directory';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    let filepaths = []; // Stores filepaths
    let all_data = []; // Array to store all data retrieved 
    let s3Client = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: BUCKET } }); // S3 bucket config

    // Runs functions in the series provided to ensure each function runs one after the other
    async.series([
        // Read file IDs from the event and saves in filepaths array
        function(callbackSeries) {
            console.log('Starting function...');
            event.forEach(id => {
                filepaths.push(`${id}.json`);
            });
            console.log('All filenames pushed.');
            callbackSeries();
        },
        // Fetches each file from S3 using filepaths
        // Then pushes objects from each file to the all_data array
        function(callbackSeries) {
            async.each(filepaths, (file, callback) => {
                let params = {
                    'Bucket': BUCKET,
                    'Key': s3path + file
                }
                s3Client.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
                    if(err) {
                        throw err;
                    } else {
                        if(data.Body.toString()) {
                            console.log('Fetching data...');
                            all_data.push(JSON.parse(data.Body.toString()));
                            callback();
                            console.log('Fetched.');
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            (err) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                else callbackSeries();
            });
        },
        // NOTHING IS BEING EXECUTED AFTER THIS
        // Puts object back into bucket as one merged file
        function(callbackSeries) {
            console.log('Final function.')

            // Concatenates multiple arrays in all_data into a single array
            all_data = Array.prototype.concat(...all_data);
            let params = {
                'Bucket': BUCKET,
                'Body': JSON.stringify(all_data),
                'Key': 'obj.json'
            };
            s3Client.putObject(params, (err, data) => {
                if(err) throw err;
                else console.log('Success!');
            })
        }
    ], (err) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        else console.log('End.');
    })
}
```

The first two functions in our **async.series** are running normally and all the console.log statements are executed. But our third function i.e.:

```
// Puts object back into bucket as one merged file
function(callbackSeries) {
    console.log('Final function.')

    // Concatenates multiple arrays in all_data into a single array
    all_data = Array.prototype.concat(...all_data);
    let params = {
        'Bucket': BUCKET,
        'Body': JSON.stringify(all_data),
        'Key': 'obj.json'
    };
    s3Client.putObject(params, (err, data) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        else console.log('Success!');
    })
}
```

is not being executed at all. We added a console.log statements but it doesn't seem to be executing at all.

I've consulted both AWS Support as well as async's documentation but can't seem to figure out the problem.

Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you add console messages on errors, and return it as `callback(err)`, instead of throwing?

Comment: There seems to be no change - the function itself isn't throwing any error - I think it stops execution after running the second function.

Comment: What is the timeout setting for you function? Lambda functions have a default 3 seconds timeout and terminates execution automatically. You can see more details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/resource-model.html).

Comment: Yes, thank you for highlighting that. It has been set to 5 minutes from the start just to avoid this. Lambda also throws a Timed out error if the timeout does occur - but it seems to be exiting successfully - just without executing the last function.

Comment: And `s3Client.getObjects` does not always return a callback, only inside the `if (data.Body.toString)`. Can you put the callback outside the if, to ensure it is always executed?

Comment: This was it - wow can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Kannaiyan Adding "[solved]" or other pseduo-tags to titles is not done on Stack Overflow, please don't do that to track the status of a question.